# C functions in R packages - Rsession aborted when function ends

Tags: r, c, crash, package, rstudio

### The problem

I am trying to wrap old C code into an R package.

So far, I have managed to get RStudio to compile the code, export the function, and everything in the function's body executes properly right until the end of the execution.

Then, the Rsession aborts without an error message (other than the restart session buttons).

My question is: why? and how do i fix it?

**EDIT:** i found a way to make it work, it's at the end of this post, but I am still without answers to both questions.

### Code bits

The wrapper looks like this:

```
#' @useDynLib mypackage main_
#' @export
cellid <- function(args) {

  # Example input:
  # args <- "cell -p ~/Projects/Colman/HD/scripts/cellMagick/data/images/parameters.txt -b /tmp/Rtmp7fjlFo/file2b401093d715 -f /tmp/Rtmp7fjlFo/file2b402742f6ef -o ~/Projects/Colman/HD/uscope/20200130_screen_act1_yfp/1/Position001/out"

  argv <- strsplit(args, " ")[[1]]  # Split arguments
  argc <- length(argv)  # Get length

  .C(main_, as.integer(argc), as.character(argv))
}
```

The actual function looks like:

```
int main_(int* aargc, char* argv[]){

  ... DO A LOT OF STUFF ...

  return 1;
}
```

## What I've tried

As I said before, if I go looking for the effects of the function on the expected system files, i find everything there. The only way I have to prevent the Rsession from crashing is to raise an error before the return:

```
int main_(int* argc, char* argv[]){

  ... DO A LOT OF STUFF ...

  error("everything works up to this point");
  return 1;
}
```

I have tried many things, quite blindly. For example, changing int to void at the function definition and omitting the return statement does not help.

I used lldb as suggested [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#src-debugging), and out of it  got the following:

```
Process 7900 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'R', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00007ffff7a946f5 libc.so.6`__strlen_avx2 + 21
libc.so.6`__strlen_avx2:
->  0x7ffff7a946f5 <+21>: vpcmpeqb (%rdi), %ymm0, %ymm1
    0x7ffff7a946f9 <+25>: vpmovmskb %ymm1, %eax
    0x7ffff7a946fd <+29>: testl  %eax, %eax
    0x7ffff7a946ff <+31>: jne    0x7ffff7a947f0            ; <+272>
```

Which I am not able to interpret, my C skills are basically zero.

### Narrowing down the cause

I have only been able to narrow down the problem to that part in which the C function ends, and R must continue (I guess).

Perhaps the problem is in the pointer objects (`argv` and `argc`). I have noticed that `argc` and `argv` change their contents throughout the execution of the function (i.e. they are shortened, see below).

At the beginning of the function:

```
Input argument number (argc[0]): 9
Input argument (argv[i] for printf): cell -p ~/Projects/Colman/HD/scripts/cellMagick/data/images/parameters.txt -b /tmp/Rtmplr4Q90/file26f12a94a144 -f /tmp/Rtmplr4Q90/file26f175cd02e5 -o ~/Projects/Colman/HD/uscope/20200130_screen_act1_yfp/1/Position001/out
```

At the end of the function:

```
Input argument number (argc[0]): 1
Input argument (argv[i] for printf): cell
```

Though i am not sure if this can be a problem, this side-effect is caused normally by glib's [g_option_context_parse](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-I18N.html) parsing of arguments.

Suspiciously for me, commenting everything after the `g_option_context_parse` line still causes the segfault, but commenting that line **and** everything after it does not cause the segfault.

Is R expecting to find argc and argv unchanged? Would it crash when it doesn't?

---

Unfortunately this is as far as I have been able to get on my own.

I have tried to keep this question short, but the complete [source of the C program](https://github.com/naikymen/cellID-linux/) is available (`main` is defined at `cell.c`).

I'd appreciate your help. Let me know how I can improve my question, if it would help.

Comment: Means you passed a NULL or unaligned pointer to `strlen`. Check that the stack is 16-byte aligned.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, unfortunately I do not think I understand. If `strlen` is a C function or variable, there are no uses of it in main.

Only in another file there is:

`char exposure[]="Exposure: "; int last; last=strlen(exposure);`

There is also `#define max_strlen 500` at `cell.c` outside the main function.

With respect to your suggestion `Check that the stack is 16-byte aligned.` I will read up and see if i can understand it.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's your problem. `vpcmpeqb` (an x86 instruction) probably requires the argument to be 16-byte aligned, and because your stack isn't aligned it probably doesn't work.

Comment: I'm no AVX expert but I do recall that being an issue when I tried to call my C functions from assembly.

Comment: Would this explain the observed behavior of the function? (segfaulting / crashing R at the end). I'm afraid I do not know what to do next with this information. Im only a biologist :S I find great difficulty in handling these terms.

Comment: I doubt that it's the return that's actually causing the failure (although that may be possible). You should check in with your IT department.

Comment: Unfortunately I am the equivalent of the IT department at my institute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207131/discussion-between-s-s-anne-and-naiky).

Comment: You should put your solution in an answer instead of a comment. Also, `argc` should be a parameter, not an array, and `argv[argc]` should be `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks again @S.S.Anne I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

### A hacky solution

I found that `g_option_context_parse` changes `argv` in a way that when printed it shows null values in all positions > 1:

```
cell (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null)
```

This not in conflict with glib's documentation.

But, if during the printing loop at the end of the script I assign non-null stuff to each position in the array (i.e. `argv[i] = "";`) the Rsession no longer aborts after the function finishes.

Even though this does "make it work", I don't really know why this happens, and my fix much more of a hack than what I'm comfortable with.

I'll accept answers from someone savvy on how R and C interact through `.C` who can explain why this happened and how to prevent it more elegantly.